# Is it the correct way to implement belongs_to relation with factory girl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, factory-bot

I have a realy easy model. A user have a role_id which depends of a role table (id, name) with a role reference.

I want create users of any types on my rspec test, with factory girl.

My first idea is something like that

```
factory :role do
  name "guest"
  factory :role_admin do
    name "admin"
  end
  factory :role_supervisor do
    name "supervisor"
  end
  etc... I have a lot a different roles
end



factory :user do
  email
  password '123456'
  password_confirmation '123456'
  association :role, factory: :role

  factory :admin do
    association :role, factory: :role_admin
  end
  factory :supervisor do
    association :role, factory: :role_supervisor
  end
  etc... I have a lot a different roles
end
```

In my model I have a simple method :

```
def is(role_name) 
  return self.role.name == role_name
end
```

It's the correct way do to? Do I realy need to create a factory for the role?
Can I make a stub for this function in factory girl for each role?

I realy new with all that test stuff, thanks.

Comment: Does your `role` table have something else than an id and a name? If no, I would recommend having a look at Single Table Inheritance, it would allow you to have a class per role.

Comment: For the moment, there is only id and role (I need a role table because roles are associated with different model/action in other table). But my question is more relationated with factory girl implementation.  The single table inheritance can help me for that?

Comment: No not at all, it won't help you dry your factories, I was just recommending having a look at it in case it might suits your needs for the following development :)

Comment: Ok thanks, could be util anyway

Answer (score 0):

Factories should reflect your models.

```
class User
  has_many :products
end

class Product
  belongs_to :user
end

factory :user do
  products
end

factory :product do
end
```

If you want to have special cases (understand roles in your case) you can define `traits`:

```
factory :user do

  traits :admin do
  end

  factory :admin_user, traits: [:admin]

end
```

More information on traits [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#traits).

Comment: I was using inheritance : https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#inheritance  It's not correct?

Comment: inheritance is for same class. If you don't have something like `class Admin < User`, you should not use it